# A condition for summable series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, arithmetic

Assume that $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a decreasing sequence in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$. Show that there exist two sequences $(r_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ that tend to infinity such that:

- $s_n=o(r_n)$ and $r_n=o(n)$,
- $n r^{-1}_n a_{s_n}=o(1)$,
- $n^{-1}r_n \sum_{i=1}^{r_n} i\cdot a_i=o(1)$.

I notice that when $a_n=O(\frac{1}{n \log n})$ then the sequences $r_n=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log(\log(n))}$ and $s_n=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(\log(\log(n)))^2}$ works. What about the general case?

Comment: Can you clean up your notation? What is $n^{-1}r$ supposed to mean?

Comment: Is it better now?